# Internal floppy will not automatically mount

Tags: 11.04, floppy

I cannot get the floppy drive to auto mount in natty 11.04 .
I can mount it using `udisks --mount /dev/fd0` in a terminal.
Iwas told that all recent versions of ubuntu have same problem and that I would need to change back to an older version of udisks.
I was told to look for version 1.0.1 in syaptic pk mng but it only shows ver 1.0.2 any help on where to get sdisks ver 1.0.1 or other fix would be great .
Thanks.

p.s.  fairly new to ubuntu so easier is better

Comment: 11.04 is no longer supported; you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open disk manager and select floppy . in settings auto-mount is must checked

[image: first] [image: second] (in my lang , auto-mount , first one in photo second